# Banco de dados não salva os dados em php, apesar de não retornar erro

Tags: php, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá :)
estou iniciando o aprendizado com PHP, tentando inserir dados do banco de dados. Apesar de não retornar erro, os dados não são salvos. Eis o codigo:

```
    <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","mazzu","");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"aulasphp");

    $nome="Matheus";
    $username="mazzu";
    $email="email@mail.com";
    $senha="123";
    $tel=9999-99999;
    $status="ok";
    $obs="ok";


    $insere="insert into tb_cadastro values (NULL ,'$nome','$username',$email,'$senha','$tel','$status','$obs')";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$insere);




    mysqli_close($con);

?>



<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Aula 30</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Veja se assim aparece algum erro: `$res=mysqli_query($con,$insere) or die(mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: @rray corrigindo: `die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Uma boa prática é informar os campos após a tabela `tb_cadastro(coluna1,coluna2....)`

Comment: `$email` é uma string (varchar), e deve estar entre aspas simples no seu SQL

Comment: Obrigado! O erro era esse pequeno detalhe das aspas simples! erro apareceu quando coloque echo mysqli_error($con);

Comment: Fica esperto que o valor de $tel=9999-99999; vai retornar -90000. Para retornar  9999-99999 coloque-o entre aspas conforme os demais $tel="9999-99999";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente está ocorrendo um erro com o seu SQL que não é reportado nativamente pelo PHP. Para ver o erro gerado no MySQL utilize a função do php `mysqli_error` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Coloque um `echo mysqli_error($con);` depois que você executa a query (e antes de fechar a conexão).

Comment: Obrigado! Era um erro na sintaxe do SQL que apareceu graças a sua dica :)

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser incompatibilidade de tipos na sua tabela. Ex: tentando inserir um varchar em um int, verifique se não é isso. Caso não seja, utilize a função `mysqli_error.`

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$insere) or die (mysqli_error($con));
```